# Como criar um produto via SQL no Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce

Estou criando um snippet para adcionar um produto no wordpress. Mas percebi que não basta inserir o produto na tabela wp_posts. A query funciona, é inserido o item no banco de dados, mas o produto não é exibido na tela de produtos.

```
    <?php
$connect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$sql     = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (49, 1, '2019-07-31 11:15:10', '2019-07-31 11:15:10', 'texto_sql_diff', 'novidadediff', 'texto_sql_desc', 'publish', 'open', 'closed', '', 'novidadediff', '', '', '2019-07-31 11:15:14', '2019-07-31 11:15:14', '', 0, 'http://duffplugin.atwebpages.com/?post_type=product&#038;p=48', 0, 'product', '', 0)";
if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<script>console.log('tudo OK!)</script>";
} else {
    echo "Error " . $sql . ' ' . $connect->connect_error;
}
$connect->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Wordpress é uma plataforma de CMS criada inicialmente para uso em blogs. Com o suporte aos plugins, foi sendo possível acrescentar funcionalidades, como o WooCommerce.

Os campos fornecidos inicialmente na tabela `wp_posts` são insuficientes para o que o WC se propõe, por isso ele faz uso (como a maioria dos plugins) da tabela `wp_postmeta`.

Os campos que são registrados no `wp_postmeta` depende de quais funcionalidades do WooCommerce você utiliza e se há plugins auxiliares.

Para isto, verifique algum produto que tenha sido cadastrado pelo WC. Para isso você pode usar:

```
SELECT id, post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "product";
```

Dos registros retornado, escolha um ID e rode a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = {id_escolhido};
```

Dessa forma você conseguirá quais são as metas adicionadas ao banco e poderá adicionar os registros que deseja.